# CSS will not apply to new page although file paths are no different

Tags: css

I am using the same style sheet for 2 pages (index.html & contact.html). All styling has been applied to index.html. Now I have copied and pasted the same code into contact.html, but have found that the new CSS styling I have tried to use will not apply to this page. The pathfile to the style.css sheet has not been changed. What I don't understand is why some of the styling is being applied from the other page but when trying to add new styling it does not?

Comment: Have you checked the "How to ask questions " https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ? It would be easier to answer seeing some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache or going incognito/private browsing

Comment: Michael, thanks for the response! I actually ended up figuring out why it wasn't working. It was because I was adding styles after my media query and I was unaware that could affect my CSS!

Answer (score 1):

Are you applying new styles using classes or ids? Id is unique, while classes are reusable. Also if you have inline styling it will override the stylesheet. Can you post your code as an example?

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the response! I actually ended up figuring out why it wasn't working. It was because I was adding styles after my media query and I was unaware that could affect my CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Well there can be a couple of reasons for this:

- Make sure that your `stylesheet` is properly loading. I don't know if you are using in page styling or an external stylesheet but make sure that it actually exists there.
  How can you do that? When you open the `contact.html` page in the browser, hit `Ctrl + U` if you are using windows or `Command + U` if you are using Mac. If it is an internal styling, you will be able to see the actual code there. If you are using an `external` stylesheet make sure that the `<link>` tag exists in the page. If it exists the right click on it and select `Open file in a new tab`. If you see can see the code in the next tab. It means that your styles are properly loading.
- Make sure that your elements in the `html` page and `stylesheet` file have the same appropriate names. For example `#` of `id`'s and `.` for classes.
- If everything is okay then it can be a `cache` issue. Since browsers cache the static assets, you should consider refreshing the cache by `Hard Reloading` the page. How can you do that? It's simple, just hit `Ctrl + Shift + R` if you are using windows or `Command + Shift + R` if you are using Mac. If these keys don't work, just click and hold the reload button on the browser until it shows a dropdown. Then simply select `Hard Reload`.

In case it doesn't work, then send us a link to your webpage. I'm here to help you. Just let me now :-)

Comment: Zahid, thanks for the response! I actually ended up figuring out why it wasn't working. It was because I was adding styles after my media query and I was unaware that could affect my CSS!